# Copying file into array but it won't print?

Tags: c, arrays, printing, fault

I'm trying to read a file onto an array  in C and I believe I have done that part correctly. However, I keep getting a segmentation fault when I try and copy it to an output file. Can someone help me find the cause of it?

```
char* inputStr;

long inputSize;

FILE* input;
FILE* output;

fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
inputSize = ftell(input);
rewind(input);
inputStr = malloc((inputSize +1) * (sizeof(char)));
fread(inputStr, sizeof(char), inputSize, input);
fclose(input);


fprintf(output, "%s", inputStr);


fclose(output);
```

Comment: You need to terminate your string 'inputStr[inputSize] = 0'. However, be aware that if your file has null characters in it the whole file will not printed. You may want to use fwrite() instead of fprintf.

Comment: You also need to fopen() input and output, I'm assuming you just omitted that part.

Comment: I terminated the string like you said but I still keep getting the segmentation fault.

Comment: Did you use fopen() on input and output? Did you check their return values?

Comment: Yes. I just omitted them here.

Comment: Ok, well, post a *complete* example. And check *ALL* return statues from all your system calls and don't ignore compiler warnings.fseek, fopen, ftell, fread, all tell you in their return status if they failed or not.

Comment: I just figured it out! It was a simple typo. Your suggestion to terminate the string fixed everything. Thank you!

Comment: Note that files can have different modes (binary or text). When opened in text mode what you get in your array may not exactly match what is on disk. It translates line endings on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't open the files! You need to open the files before doing an fseek(), ftell(), ...